# crm onpremise 2013 domain change

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I need to change the existing domain for my crm 2013 onpremise which is running with application on one server, database on another server and ssrs on another server, lets say for example if my crm, db and ssrs servers are with abc.com domain and crm url is https://crmtest.abc.com now all the servers are going to change to xyz.abc.com so my url should be accesible through https://crmtest.xyz.abc.com

So now what all steps I need to consider to make a smooth transition to new domain for my production environment.
Do I need to buy new CRM 2013 onpremise licenses?
How to do the User mapping to new domain users?

Kindly help!!!

Comment: You might want to refer to the [CRM 2013 Implementation Guide](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40322).

Answer (score 0):

I am making the assumption that you are just going to be changing the website domain for the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Web site.  You don't mention if you are using an Internet facing deployment, but with the domain URLs, I'm assuming that you've also got a Microsoft AD FS server involved in order to configure your Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 for an Internet Facing Deployment.

If the domain is changed, you would need to get an updated wildcard certificate for the new domain and install it on both the AD FS Server and the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Server.

This is a fairly involved process, but below is part of the steps that would need to be followed for this, noting that you'd also need to update the internal and external DNS entries that currently point to your Microsoft Dynamics CRM Server URLs to exist in the new domain.

If you change the certificates used by Microsoft Dynamics CRM and AD FS, follow these steps.

1. Add the new certificate to the AD FS server.
   a. Import the new certificate to the AD FS server.
   b. Grant the ADFSAppPool account Read permission to the new certificate
   c. Bind the new certificate to the AD FS website.
2. Add the new certificate to the Microsoft Dynamics CRM server.
   a. Import the new certificate to the Microsoft Dynamics CRM server.
   b. Grant the CRMAppPool account Read permission to the new certificate
   c. Bind the new certificate to the Microsoft Dynamics CRM website.
   Start the Deployment Manager and run the Configure Claims-Based Authentication Wizard to use the new certificate.
3. On the AD FS server, update all the relying party trusts used by Microsoft Dynamics CRM.
4. If the certificate subject name changes, update the root domain web addresses to match the new subject name.
5. Run the IISReset command on the AD FS and Microsoft Dynamics CRM servers.  Note that if you are using Microsoft AD FS on Windows Server 2012 R2 or later, the IISReset command isn't needed on the AD FS server.

In addition to the [CRM 2013 Implementation Guide](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40322) that Aron mentioned, I'd also recommend the [Configuring Claims-based Authentication for Microsoft Dynamics CRM Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41701) as a great guide for how to go through a deployment or deployment change like this.  Note that this document is quite lengthy, but I frequently reference this document and the topic "Example DNS Settings - AD FS and Microsoft Dynamics CRM on separate servers" for what needs to be updated in DNS.

Comment: Hi Chad Rexin, Its not just domain change for website, we are going to change domain for all the servers, Application, Database, SSRS, and ADFS, all the servers are changing to new child domain

Comment: Will you have the original domain at the same time or will it all be switched?  If you won't have the original domain at all, then you'd need to migrate the data to a new CRM installation or would have to import the organization and then change the domainname info of users in the SystemUserBase table of that organization.  All of the requirements that I posted here would also still be required.  If you have the original domain and setup a trust, you can just do the import organization process and certificate/ADFS updates.

Comment: We will not be using same domain, domain will will be changed